# Consequence of entropy increasing with time

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, universe, arrow-of-time

Our bodies are a highly ordered collection of atoms. Entropy is a measure of disorder. Since the entropy of the universe increases with time, does that imply that humans will necessarily become extinct at some point of time?

Comment: Entropy is defined at dS=deltaQ_rev/T or dS>=dQ/T. Can you show me how you want to apply this formula to the universe? What is the reversible heat flow here? Irrespective of that, disorder has absolutely nothing to do with the fact that all species either become extinct or evolve into new species. Nature simply does not have a need to keep a particular species around.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect entropy is a trickier concept that someone might think, since it measures way more than just disorder of a system. From the microscopic point of view, it's strongly related to the possible configurations that are accessible to any system and defines its main properties and behaviours.

But let's stick to your question: the fact that the entropy of the universe increases with time (although it might be more precise to say that it **doesn't decrease** with time) comes from our assumption that the universe is a closed system. Nevertheless, human body interact constantly with the environment around it and the continuous exchange of matter and heat makes us impossible to think at humans as if they were closed systems.
For this reason I'm prone to say that your suggestion does not strictly imply that humans will become extinct, though it is an honest assumption.

If you want to explore more the concept of entropy related to time and/or our perception of it, I know that Carlo Rovelli in some of his books (for example in "The order of Time" or "What is time? What is space?") briefly talks about that specific topic, though from a philosophical point of view, without too many scientific contributions.
Lastly, another interesting point of view can be found in Mauro Dorato's book "Che cos'è il tempo? Einstein, Gödel e l'esperienza comune", even though I'm pretty sure there are no available translations from the Italian language, in which it is written.